# TYPO3 7.6.11 RealURL: wrong news on detail page

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news

I installed the extensions **Speaking URLs (realurl)** and **News**. But if I enable RealURL every news (list view) is redirecting to the first news-item I clicked.

**The URL of the news detail page is correct but the content is wrong.**
All caches via Install Tool are empty...

Does somebody knows how to fix it?
I'm thankful for every help.

Comment: Can you include your realurl configuration?

Comment: There is currently an issue with TYPO3 v7.6.11 and realurl 2.0.15: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/253

Comment: apart from that, could you please provide a sample of the realurl-generated link, too?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is cache issue. first of all take DB backup after clear all realurl cache tables in DB.